# Does SQL Server Data Need to be Spatial

Tags: sql-server, well-known-text, sql-server-spatial

In reference to my [previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158331/sql-server-spatial-querying).

I am looking for the benefits of telling SQL Server your data is spatial.  For instance, I have a duplicate of that table generated by the *Shape2SQL* tool (**see previous question**).  The major difference is it is not a *spatial* table, but I have a field where I am storing the well-known text in lat/long (e.g. POINT(-82.2990401 38.9186892)).  I found I was able to run a similar query that worked to get me the data I was requesting.

```
declare @poly geometry = 'POLYGON((-82.8113 39.690, -81.145 39.725, -80.717 38.74, -82.813 38.614, -82.8113 39.690))'

SELECT * FROM [TABLE]
WHERE @poly.STIntersects(WKT) <> 0;
```

I am looking to see the **real** benefits to telling SQL Server that you're dealing with spatial data.  The only two things I can think of off the top of my head are spatial indexing and being able to visualize your data in the query results window within SQL Server Management Studio.

I am looking for the pros of SQL Server serving spatial data.  This is for a personal website, and I have no desire to invest in running a spatial server instance like ArcGIS Server or GeoServer.  I am curious if I will be better off leaving things in a table and just using WKT in my queries or if I should really be using a geom/geog object.

Answer (score 2):

> spatial indexing and being able to visualize your data

You're absolutely right on those two counts.

I would make one more point; building the geometry object is computationally expensive, especially on large or complex data sets. Performance and scaling will suffer, because the database is having to build the geometry on-the-fly.

Your query will perform better if the geometry object was already created and stored in a field.

Also, I think your query should look more like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLE]
WHERE @poly.STIntersects(geometry::STGeomFromText(WKT)) <> 0;
```

Comment: So, whenever I am running a query where I am taking a WKT and doing something with it, is SQL Server converting that in the backend to a geometry object?

Comment: Correct, `declare @poly geometry` is building the geometry and storing it temporarily.

Comment: Ok, but the basic idea I was thinking was that `declare @poly geometry` part would take an polygon that would be created elsewhere and finding which WKT's from my table would intersect or whatever other operation.  It isn't tied directly to the values stored within the table.

Comment: I've added a bit to my answer, check out this link to see if it helps you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933899.aspx